# Set precise time on a video using javascript

Tags: media9, javascript, video

Hi i'm trying to get a button to set the video time a precise point.
The code listed below is what i've made up till now but its not working.
i think because it cant get the document.getElementById.
Anyone have an idea how to resolve this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage[pdftex]{insdljs}
\usepackage{media9}
\begin{insDLJS}{mydljs}{some comment}
function stop(){
var vid = document.getElementById("bunny.mp4"); 
vid.currentTime=5;
}
\end{insDLJS}

\begin{document}
\includemedia[width=0.6\linewidth,height=0.6\linewidth,activate=pageopen,
passcontext,
transparent,
addresource=bunny.mp4,
flashvars={source=bunny.mp4}
]{}{VPlayer.swf}


\begin{Form}
    \PushButton[onclick={stop();}]{5 sec}\\
    \TextField[name=somefield, width=4em]{Any way to hide e.g. this text?}
\end{Form}
\end{document}ode here
```

Comment: Your comment should  be under here or the answer. First off have you tried to ensure your source file is re-encoded per the suggestion in the answer e.g. have you tried ffmpeg to regenerate a compatible file using similar values for profile  fmt etc once you find a match that works then adjust for optimum speed etc

Comment: I edited the answer to include an example with embedded video file that was re-encoded to allow for seeking.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript is *not* required.

Additional control buttons can be inserted with the `\mediabutton` command. Look into the [`media9` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/media9/doc/media9.pdf#page=20) for examples.

If you cannot seek precisely enough into the video, it may be necessary to re-encode the video with a higher number of key frames.

For example, a key frame at every second, using `ffmpeg` with options `-g ...` and `-r ...` (frame rate) having the same value:

```
ffmpeg -i video-in.mp4 -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 30 -r 30 video-out.mp4
```

---

**Update:** [Example on Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/dbtvqtrxssnc) with embedded video file `example-movie.mp4` from package [**`mwe`**](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mwe/example-movie.mp4), re-encoded with a keyframe at every second using above-listed command line.

---

Example with streamed video:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{media9}
\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

\includemedia[
  label=videoexample,
  width=16em,height=9em,
  activate=pageopen,
  passcontext,
  transparent,
  flashvars={source=https://ia800501.us.archive.org/10/items/BigBuckBunny_310/big_buck_bunny_640_512kb.mp4}
]{}{VPlayer.swf}

\mediabutton[
  mediacommand=videoexample:play[(25)],
  mediacommand=videoexample:pause
]{\fbox{25~s}}
\mediabutton[
  mediacommand=videoexample:play[(50)],
  mediacommand=videoexample:pause
]{\fbox{50~s}}
\mediabutton[
  mediacommand=videoexample:play[(150)],
  mediacommand=videoexample:pause
]{\fbox{150~s}}

\end{document}
```